# java.security.AccessControlException in setting JAXB converter in Java 8

Tags: java-8, jaxb

While working on upgrading java version for one of our project to 1.8 from existing 1.6, I am getting Spring's `BeanCreationException` in running automated tests with below as root cause:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.xml.bind.JAXBPermission" "setDatatypeConverter")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.setDatatypeConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:303)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145)
```

I'm using `jaxb-impl-2.2.3.jar`.

I couldn't find much on this on googling, any help is really appreciated.